# What angular2 RxJS subscription pattern should I use?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using RxJS with Angular2.

I often find myself emitting to a private subject in an Angular2 service which emits to a public stream / observable.

The typical pattern I am using in my component is ..

```
ngOnInit() {
  service.myStream$.subscribe( ... )
}

clickSomethingHandler() {
  service.emit(this.someValue);
}
```

And in my service ...

```
private mySubject = new Subject<any>();

public myStream$ = mySubject.map( ... ) // etc

public emit(value) {
    mySubject.next(value);
}
```

Is this the best approach? Any other approaches or improvements on this?

Thanks

Comment: You could make `mySubject` public and bypass `emit()` - `service.mySubject.next(this.someValue)`. This way you can access it directly if you need some component specific stream processing - `service.mySubject.asObservable().filter(componentFilterFn).subscribe()`. Other then that LGTM...

Comment: If you are looking for a really sophisticated pattern on how to handle states in angular2, have a look at ngrx: https://github.com/ngrx/store